# java.sql.Exception ClosedConnection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ibatis

I am getting the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Closed
>   Connection    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getMetaData(PhysicalConnection.java:1508)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.moveToNextResultsSafely(SqlExecutor.java:348)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.handleMultipleResults(SqlExecutor.java:320)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeQueryProcedure(SqlExecutor.java:277)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.ProcedureStatement.sqlExecuteQuery(ProcedureStatement.java:34)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(GeneralStatement.java:173)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryForList(GeneralStatement.java:123)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:614)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:588)
>     at
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$3.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:268)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.executeWithListResult(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:219)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:266)
>     at
>   gov.hud.pih.eiv.web.authentication.AuthenticationUserDAO.isPihUserDAO(AuthenticationUserDAO.java:24)
>     at
>   gov.hud.pih.eiv.web.authorization.AuthorizationProxy.isAuthorized(AuthorizationProxy.java:125)
>     at
>   gov.hud.pih.eiv.web.authorization.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
>     at

I am really stumped and can't figure out what could be causing this error. I am not able to reproduce the error on my machine but on production it is coming a lot of times.  I am using iBatis in the whole application so there are no chances of my code not closing connections.

We do have stored procedures that run for a long time before they return results (around 15 seconds).

does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this? I dont think raising the # of connections on the application server will fix this issue buecause if connections were running out then we'd see "Error on allocating connections"

Sample code snippet:

```
this.setSqlMapClientTemplate(getSqlTempl());
getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("authentication.isUserDAO", parmMap);
this.setSqlMapClientTemplate(getSqlTemplDW());
List results = (List) parmMap.get("Result0");
```

I am using validate in my connection pool.

Comment: Is your problem similar to [IBATIS-539](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IBATIS-539) or not at all?

Comment: @Pascal I don't think it is related as I do not use any proxyConnecitons

Comment: Ok. Maybe have a look or search for existing issues anyway.

Comment: How long running are these connections?  Is it possible that a piece of network gear is terminating long running TCP connections between the client and db server?  We had such a problem with our DataSources a ways back.

Comment: hmmm how were you able to identify this issue?  I mean how would you track something like this? client in this case is the Appserver going to DB server. Some of these connections MIGHT be long.

Comment: We were going through some Cisco Cascade switches as well as some firewall blades and our network engineer was clueful. One thing to try is to setup a netcat socket between the client and server and see if it self terminates.  Another idea would be to write a simple java program that establishes a single database connection and see if it drops after a while.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace, the likely cause is that you are continuing to use a ResultSet after close() was called on the Connection that generated the ResultSet.

Comment: ...how can that be? could my ORM (iBatis) be doing this? because in my code I do not use ResultSet either.  I just give iBatis the stored proc name...supply the parameters and except a result set back.

Answer (score 0):

What is your DataSource framework? Apache Commons DBCP?
do you use poolPrepareStatement property in data source configuration?

Check the following:

1. Make sure testOnBorrow and testOnReturn are true and place a simple validationQuery like select 0 from dual.
   Do you use au
2. do you use autoCommit? Are you using START TRANSACTION, COMMIT in your stored procedures? After several days of debugging we found out that you can't mix transaction management both in Java and in SQL - you have to decide on one place to do it. Where are you doing yours?

Edit your question with answers to this, an we'll continue from there.

Comment: I used Spring framework along with iBatis. 1. testOnBorrow and testOnReturn only apply to apache commons DBCP.  On glassfish appserver I do have validation query. 2. yes stored procedures do have start transaction and commit. but I DO NOT use autocommit on java side. so we are not mix matching

Comment: Do you use the DECLARE HANDLER in your stored procedure? I mean, how do you issue a ROLLBACK command if something goes wrong in the middle of your stored procedure? It might leave locks on the connection, which never closes since you're using a pool

Answer (score 0):

When a db server reboots, or there are some problems with a network, all the connections in the connection pool are broken and this usuall requires a reboot of application server

And if broken connection detected, you shold create a new one to replace it in connection pool. It's common problem called deadly connections.

Comment: ok... but this happens in a live environemnt when DB server is up